# EFCore Framework Scaffolding overwrites DBContext file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I am trying to leverage scaffolding for EntityFrameworkCore to create an entity framework models for existing Sql Server database. This works fine and it did create the context file and all the tables.

However going forward I still want to continue to update the DB and get the model updated based on Database changes. This works fine with force flag on Scaffolding as it overwrites the tables with new changes.

The main concern I have is scaffolding needs db connection string which gets included in the DBContext file. And on running scaffolding command this file gets overwritten as well. Ideally i would like to save it in config file and have different value based on environments. However this means every time model is updated all my config changes are lost and I need to manually reapply the same

Is there any efficient way to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use EF Core Power Tools, and the use the constructor that takes a DbContextOptionsBuilder and specify the privider and the corresponding connection string outside the DbContext class.

Comment: Thanks will check out. Is there an example you can point me too?

Comment: Yes, the product documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext